# Fetch external data and populate form in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In short:

I would like to fill in some form fields in django admin, before I click the save button, based on the input in another field.

The longer version:

I have 2 models, `SteamGame` and `GameInfo` which has a ForeignKey to `SteamGame`. The `SteamGame` table gets filled once a day with *all* the games listed on Steam, by fetching and parsing http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/, the `GameInfo` table gets filled manually using the admin site. When adding to `GameInfo` I select the game from `SteamGame`. Some of the fields are for info I add myself, some of the fields I want to be populated after selecting the game and fetching https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=GAMEID&l=en for that information.

Are there some magic Django functions I can use to accomplish this? Or any other suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So, why aren't you also populating the GameInfo with data through your daily script? I assume you are storing the steam GameID in your SteamGame model, so you can build the URL pretty easily

Comment: Currently that is the setup I have, but not all the GameID's can be accessed through the API resulting in tons if if-else checks and then still having the script quit on an error. Also, there are about 71k+ games so that's a LOT of requests. I'm not going to add info on every single game so I figured this would be more efficient than the current setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass a javascript file and using query you can make a ajax call and append the values to the form using jquery .

```
 class HistoryConfigurationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       class Media:
              js = ("customjs/yourjsfile.js",)
```

and create a yourjsfile.js in static folder of you project.note for using jquery in django admin instead of using $(document).ready we use "jq" instead of "$" symbol

Comment: Thanks! This worked :) Well, sadly enough in my case it didn't because of CORS which was to be expected.. but I can work around that by calling a django page which in turn fetches the data. Also thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53741300/2111837, but I choose to accept this answer as it also explains to not use the `$` symbol which pointed me to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to achieve that.

On your admin model, add this to call for a custom javascript:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = ('/static/js/myMagicJavascriptThatDoesAllThisStuff.js', 
)
```

The JS will allow the user to see what will be saved BEFORE saving it.
If you want to pull the information after the save, you should override the admin save function